# How to extend two monitors in a freerdp session?

Tags: rdp, freerdp, xfreerdp

I would like to extend my two monitors in a FreeRDP session. I want something like [this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/oFrYd4JDSmA/maxresdefault.jpg). In Windows, we normally go to the displays settings and there we choose to extend the monitors, but I don't know how to do it with FreeRDP. When I run my FreeDRP session, if I specify `/span`, Windows recognizes my two monitors as a very large one. [Here](https://i.ibb.co/ZWF6bY2/problem.jpg) it is what it currently looks like. I already tried specifying `/multimon`, `/monitors:0,1` and `/span` options to `xfreerdp`, but nothing works. How can I achieve what I want?

Thanks.